# Concatenate char columns without using `for xml path` in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have got SQL Server 2005 and I want to get result like in the picture, I dont want to use `for xml path` method and make different way.

[image]

Comment: The most general way in SQL Server is to use `for path xml`.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason why you wouldn't want to use `FOR XML PATH` (other than you not wanting to use it)? It is the only conscise way to do string concatenation in 2005.

Comment: i dont have any reason but i am worried about performance.
Does not the server tire? Do you have any idea for it?

Comment: Concatenation with FOR XML PATH up until SQL Server 2016 is accepted as the best way to concatenate strings. In SQL Server 2017 onwards, there is STRING_AGG.

Answer (score 0):

As @TT says in the comments "Concatenation with FOR XML PATH up until SQL Server 2016 is accepted as the best way to concatenate strings.", so you should use it.